# backup json file with php?

Tags: php, zip

I have a json files in my project.
I will create zip file for donwload by clients.
I have write this:

```
<?php
...
if($_POST['save'])
{
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('files.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
{
    $zip->addFile('data.json');
    $zip->addFile('config.json');
    $zip->close();
}
}
...
```

After the reopening of the Zip, I got an error. The file files.zip don't exist.

Suppose that these two files are in the same folder.

Is the code that I did wrong? If wrong, please kindly tell me how to fix it.

Comment: This Code works fine.... where is open file `code`

Comment: yes; i thonk, but i have no file . i don't understand

Comment: your mean is at first time code will work fine but in another times got error ?

Comment: i have a error on write file: directory error but the directory destination exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution with getcwd() ;-)

```
<?php
...
if($_POST['save'])
{
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open(getcwd().'/files.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
{
    $zip->addFile('data.json');
    $zip->addFile('config.json');
    $zip->close();
}
}
...
```